# Allow users with a buttons to change the web site viewport size as per device dimension

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

First see the web site template http://thevectorlab.net/theme/?theme=Admin%20Lab

this web site template made a provision to resize the site at run time for desktop mobile and tablet when click occur on relevant buttons. see the link and see there are few button at top left where user click to resize the site and see how web site look like when user visit the site from mobile or tablet, desktop etc.

suppose i want to develop a site where i will provide 3 buttons where user click and my web site will resize at run time for desktop mobile and tablet. so user can see and feel how the site look like when user visit the site from mobile or tablet, desktop etc.

so tell me how could i develop such dynamic resize functionality with multiple button when user click on any. thanks

Comment: This looks like a very simple task. All you need to do is to dynamically set the width of the container that wraps your page based on the button click. Do you some code to share that you've been trying?

Comment: i have not tried any code. i just saw the web site and getting curious to know how they provide this kind of functionality for their web site. anyone can give me small example of dynamically resize site with jsfiddle.

Comment: If you've not tried any code, it's unlikely to get an answer here at SO.

Comment: the link i posted they are not free. so i need some sample code to start the journey.